# When calling the DescribeDBInstances operation: Unrecognized filter name: tag:Name

Tags: amazon-rds, aws-cli

I'm trying to run the following command:

`aws rds describe-db-instances --filters 'Name=tag:Name,Values=*stable*' --output text --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].InstanceId'`

When I do, I get this output:

> An error occurred (InvalidParameterValue) when calling the DescribeDBInstances operation: Unrecognized filter name: tag:Name

According to the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/rds/describe-db-instances.html), it looks like I should be able to pass in a string to filter by, but I'm unsure why it's not recognizing the `tag:Name`? Is this a limitation of the `rds` command?

Answer (score 3):

According to the [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/rds/describe-db-instances.html), the `--filters` option only supports these:

> Supported filters:
>
> db-cluster-id - Accepts DB cluster identifiers and DB cluster Amazon Resource Names (ARNs). The results list will only include information about the DB instances associated with the DB clusters identified by these ARNs.
>
> db-instance-id - Accepts DB instance identifiers and DB instance Amazon Resource Names (ARNs). The results list will only include information about the DB instances identified by these ARNs.

Comment: How can I file a request to AWS to implement filter support for 'DBInstanceIdentifier'?